# Сложить все данные из JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

хочу сложить все данные полученные из json.

Имеется данный код:

```
  foreach (var capture in json.captures)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"{capture.Key}, {captures.Value.Data}");
  }
```

Все данные выводятся в консоль.

```
Пример:
1: 242
2: 532
3: 264
```

Как их все сложить? От 1 до 3. Или заранее сложить и вывести в один результат.

242 + 532 + 264 = результат.

Comment: `json.captures.Sum(v=>v.Value.Data)`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное))))) Решение было такое простое. Зато обучаюсь и получаю много опыта.

Comment: Я думаю вы можете добавить это в ответ. Я помечу его галочкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для суммирования элементов коллекции используйте LINQ, например

```
json.captures.Sum(v=>v.Value.Data)
```